# General technique for finding expected payoff of optimal “prophetic” stopping time for Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given a (finite state space, discrete-time) Markov chain $X_n$ with state space $S$ and a payoff function $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$, define $v:S\to\mathbb{R}$ as
$$
v(x) = \mathbb{E}\left[\max_n f(X_n)\mid X_0 = x\right].
$$
Here $v(x)$ is essentially the expected payoff if we know what path the chain will take in advance, since we will stop the chain at a value giving the maximum payoff (because we will know when we reach this state).

I’ve done a few problems that involved computing this $v(x)$ for different chains and payoff functions, and in each case I’ve had to rely on the specific structure of the transition matrix for that particular chain. For instance, for the case where the the chain $X_n$ has state space $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and transition probabilities
$$
p(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac 1 6 & x\neq 6\\
1 & x=y=6 \\
0& \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
and the payoff function is $f(x)=x$ for $x\neq 6$ and $f(6)=0$, I found (by conditioning on $X_1$) that
$$
v(x) = \frac{1}{6}\left(\sum_{\substack{y\in S\\ f(y)>f(x)}} v(y) + \sum_{\substack{y\in S \\ f(y)\leq f(x) \\ y\neq 6}} v(x) + f(x)\right).
$$
Then we get a “triangular” system of equations, which we can solve, beginning with $v(5)$ and proceeding downwards. (This setup models a game where you roll a die; if you get 1 through 5, you may either take your roll as your payoff and stop playing, or give up your payoff and instead play again. But if you roll 6, you get 0 payoff and the game is over.)

But this approach relies on the structure of this particular Markov chain. In particular, when conditioning on $X_1$, I needed to use the structure of the chain to handle the cases when $f(X_1) < f(x)$, since it is not clear how
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\max_n f(X_n)\mid X_0 = x,X_1=y\right]
$$
relates to $v(x)$ in general. I think this method probably generalizes to chains where the transition probabilities do not depend on the current state except for some absorbing states, but this seems pretty restrictive.

I was wondering whether there is a general technique that works for any Markov chain and payoff function for computing this function $v$, or at least for a broader class of chains.

Comment: "*Here v(x) is essentially the expected payoff if we know what path the chain will take in advance, since we will stop the chain at a value giving the maximum payoff (because we will know when we reach this state)*" I don't think this is what you have defined. $v$ is just the expectation of the maximum value of the process' path.

Comment: @Snoop Yes, $v$ is the expectation of the maximum value of the process' path. I think the idea is that if we can stop the process at any point, and we know the point at which it will attain its maximum value, then we can always stop it at that maximum value, making our expected payoff equal to the expected maximum value. ((I took this definition from my textbook, and this is how it was motivated there.)